# Blender to Unity, keep drivers

Tags: unity, drivers

I'm trying to teach myself blender and unity, and I'm currently building a simple tank. I've made the wheels and threads move correctly with the body of the tank using drivers, but when importing the asset to Unity nothing is moving when I'm moving the tank.

Question is... Is it possible to maintain the drivers when importing the asset into Unity? If not, why?

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8qZN3cjX4c see this tutorial for your problem